# Can't install Firebase in react project

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, npm, npm-install

I had to install firebase but after hitting `npm install firebase` I got this error:

```
F:\React test\my-app>npm install firebase
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ebsocket":"0.11.1","t'
```

node version: 12.16.1

npm version: 6.13.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`npm cache clean --force`

`npm install firebase`

Answer (score 0):

If after trying npm cache clean --force  installation still does not work, delete node_modules then run npm install firebase and finally run npm install, to recover all the other packages you had before.